# Rails- Authenticate a user before acces to a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello in my ruby on rails application i built a authentication system for a User scaffold.

**Session Controller**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if !user.nil? && user.authenticate(params[:password])
        session[:user_id] == user.id
        redirect_to root_url
    else
        render :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] == nil
    redirect_to login_url
  end
end
```

after the login i redirect a user to the root page called: chat_room

**Chat room controller**

```
 class ChatRoomController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user

  def index
    @current_user = User.where(id: params[:user_id]).first
  end
end
```

and in the application_controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def authenticate_user
     if session[:user_id] == nil
      redirect_to login_path
     end
   end

end
```

but whit this method the app redirect me always to the login page even if the credentials are right.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

Fix typos:

> `==` comparison
>
> `=` assignment

```
def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  if !user.nil? && user.authenticate(params[:password])
    session[:user_id] == user.id
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render :new
  end
end

def destroy
  session[:user_id] == nil
  redirect_to login_url
end
```

Should be:

```
def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  if !user.nil? && user.authenticate(params[:password])
    session[:user_id] **=** user.id
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render :new
  end
end

def destroy
  session[:user_id] = nil
  redirect_to login_url
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple only we have to put this before after just initialize

**NOTE: Hope you are using Devise gem for authentication user**

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

Example:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
  end
end
```